# Unexpected namespace prefix "app" found for tag TextView when I try to set fontFamily attribute

Tags: android, xml

I set `app:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"` on TextView and i get error: **Unexpected namespace prefix "app" found for tag TextView**. I use Android Studio 3.0. Is there any solution?

Comment: add this name space **xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"**

Comment: Have you tried with `android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"`?

Comment: I think changing TextView to android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView could fix the issue. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Changing from TextView to android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try changing `TextView` to `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView`.

Answer (score 1):

Not required

```
app:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
```

Change to ,

```
android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
```

it will work for sure.

Comment: It works depending on which version of Android you support.

Answer (score 1):

Changing `TextView` to `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView` works if I use "app" name space prefix. If I use "android" name space prefix it provides compatibility with API version 16 and higher, but I needed compatibility from API version 14 so "app" prefix solved my problem.

Comment: This is not an answer. You are commenting on other answers.

Answer (score -2):

> this is working for me

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fontFamily="cursive"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:text="hhellloSDFSDF"/>
```

Comment: Of course you don't have the same issue, you are not even using the `app` namespace

Comment: @GabrielOshiro but I have suggested alternative answer.